# How is damage reduction from armor calculated?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I'm late game and now my Armor is stupid high (I'm at 60+, I think).

Early game things do no more than a quarter heart, but late game bosses still hit me pretty hard.

So how is the damage from the armor calculated? If something was supposed to do me 10 hearts damage when I'm in my shorts, how much will I take with 10/20/30/40/50 armor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/61zbkh/psa_each_additional_armor_point_reduces_incoming/) ,

> Each additional armor point reduces incoming damage by 1/4 heart

(To a minimum of 1/4)

Furthermore

> Additionally, for defense elixirs and per-strike damage:
>
> Level 1 defense reduces damage by 1 heart (4 armor).
> Level 2 defense reduces damage by 3 hearts (12 armor).
> Level 3 defense reduces damage by 6 hearts (24 armor).

Comment: It it's flat? So 60 armor would mean that every hit I take is reduced by 15 hearts of damage?

Comment: Seems weird that it would be just flat, I should run some tests before accepting as answer.

Comment: In case the answer wasn't clear, any enemy will deal a minimum damage of 1/4 of a heart, no matter even if the armor reduces more damage than the boko itself. (if the boko has a traveler's sword, which does 5 (1 and 1/4 heart) and you have an armor defence of  10, than it will do 1/4 heart, even though your armor is more than the damage output.