# How many "hit points" is a single heart worth?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Monsters and bosses have health in terms of hit points (HP). But Link has health in terms of hearts, which can be lost at an increment of a quarter-heart at a time.

Is there some relationship between these two health standards? Does 1 heart equal 10 HP or something?

Comment: What does this even mean? What's an equivalence between heart and HP for you?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer It's not entirely specious - there are things that can hurt both the player and enemies. Bombs, falling objects, fire.

Comment: Additionally, both the player and enemies use many of the same weapons, and the power of those weapons is displayed as the amount of HP subtracted from enemies' health per hit. It's entirely reasonable to wonder what those numbers mean when it's an enemy swinging that weapon at you.

Comment: @Walt: ... and it's not guaranteed that how much damage some effect does to an enemy has any relation to how much it does to Link!

Comment: @Hurkyl then maybe a good answer would be "those are not related, and this is why", no?

Comment: @Frank That is provably false. If you wear the Champion's Tunic, you can see enemy HP. If you have a sword that does, say, 40 damage, you can see the enemy HP go down by 40 every time you hit them with it. If you give that same sword to a Bokoblin and let them hit you with it once, you will (assuming you're wearing no armor and not currently buffed with any elixirs) take 10 hearts aka 40 HP in damage.

Comment: @MageXy According to pictures, all you see is a bar, with no numerical value.  How do you know how much damage you're doing?

Comment: @Frank Like I said, the Champion's Tunic shows enemy HP over their heads if you're wearing it. [This video](https://youtu.be/M-lsoQyor_k?t=35) actually shows a good demonstration, as you can see the attack power of the weapons he switches between and you can see the damage numbers accordingly.

Comment: @MageXy Okay, that's new.  Haven't seen that in a Zelda before.  I retract my objections.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Each quarter heart is worth 1 HP. This means one heart is worth 4 HP, and once you max out your health capacity, you end up with 120 HP (30 hearts).

This might not sound like much, but remember that you have some damage mitigation that most enemies don't have. As detailed in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/304466/145980), each point of armor you have reduces incoming damage by 1 HP (1 quarter heart), and defense elixirs can add up to 24 armor to your stats. The fact that you can stop a battle to eat a four course meal also helps keep your health up.

Comment: That is actually a lot of hearts.  Is the damage also increased depending on the monster attacking or is it the same for every monster?  Like if a Bokoblin attacks you with a Boko Stick is it the same damage as a Moblin attacking you with a Boko Stick?

Comment: @fja3omega I'm guessing yes. This video (https://youtube.com/watch?t=158s&v=7DttZ_cpF3E) does say that stronger enemies wielding the same weapons do more damage but I'm not sure if that's just limited to the Master Mode.